# replacing checkout.cart.extra (shipping estimator) in cart with CMS block

Tags: cart, blocks

we want to replace the `checkout.cart.shipping` block in cart with a **CMS block**

Can this be done directly by a XML replace action? (directly tell Magento to not go look for `checkout.cart.shipping` but rather a CMS BLOCK) - the block with the shipping estimator.

Or is the only way to move `checkout.cart.shipping` to my **local/custom** folder and re-write?

thanks ;P

[image]

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this it works,

In `local.xml`

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="cms/block" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_identifier</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: Didnt work.  Hmmm

Comment: what issues you face and what content you add in static block?

Comment: Quality! Thanks for the straight forward solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart.shipping">
      <block type="cms/block" name="right-page-block">
         <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>right-page-block</block_id></action>
      </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

replace with your CMS static block id

Comment: This is not working (cache turned off). Also the block I am trying to replace  is actually checkout.cart.shipping. Question updated.

Comment: see my updated answer and put this code in your local.xml @snh_nl